# javascript with html set image position error

Tags: html

I have the follow code, it show the picture but don't set the position, where is the problem?

```
                  document.write("<IMG ALIGN='center' "+
                "style=position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100 " +
                "SRC='http://www.uairobotics.com/tomada/Images/farol.png'> " +
               "<BR><BR>");
```

thank you

Roberto

Comment: You're missing the units at `left` and `top`. It should be `left:400px`...

Comment: Also, maybe as a sidenote but still: That HTML syntax is horribly outdated, and CSS shouldn't be inlined on your elements (unless this was a quick n' dirty for the sake of the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, you missed ' in style attribute.

```
            document.write("<IMG ALIGN='center' "+
            "style='position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100' " +
            "SRC='http://www.uairobotics.com/tomada/Images/farol.png'> " +
           "<BR><BR>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write("<IMG ALIGN='center' style='position:absolute; left: 400px; top: 100px' SRC='http://www.uairobotics.com/tomada/Images/farol.png'> " +
               "<BR><BR>");
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hspwpsxv/)